# Is explicit caching required for List members of a type in F#

Tags: list, caching, f#, evaluation

My question is probably digging a bit into the question on how smart the F# compiler really is.

I have a type module that scans a configuration file and should then provide a range of IP addresses between a start and an end address.

```
type IpRange (config: string) =
    // Parse the config
    member __.StartIp = new MyIp(startIp)
    member __.EndIp = new MyIp(endIp)
```

Now I wanted to add the actual range giving me all IPs so I added

```
    member __.Range = 
        let result = new List<MyIp>()
        let mutable ipRunner = __.StartIp
        while ipRunner <= __.EndIp do
            result.Add(new MyIp(ipRunner))
            ipRunner <- (ipRunner + 1)
        result
```

which works but is not really idiomatic F#.

I then dug into the issue and came up with the following two alternatives

```
let rec GetIpRangeRec (startIp: MyIp) (endIp: MyIp) (ipList: MyIp list) = 
    if startIp <= endIp then
        GetIpRangeRec (startIp + 1) endIp (ipList@[startIp])
    else
        ipList
```

and

```
let GetIpRangeUnfold (startIp: MyIp) (endIp: MyIp) =
        startIp |> Seq.unfold(fun currentIp -> 
                                if (currentIp <= endIp) then 
                                    Some(currentIp, currentIp + 1) 
                                else 
                                    None)
```

As far as I have understood from reading up on lists and sequences, none is cached. So all three solutions would re-evalute the code to create a list whenever I try to access an item or enumerate the list.

I could solve this problem by using `Seq.cache` (and a previous cast to sequence where required) resulting in something like

```
member __.Range =
    GetIpRangeRec startIp endIp []
    |> List.toSeq
    |> Seq.cache
```

but is this really necessary?

I have the feeling that I missed something and the F# compiler actually does cache the result without explicitely telling it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists are (normally at least, I suppose there might be some weird edge case I don't know about) stored directly as their values.  Thus, your recursive function would specifically produce a list of `MyIp`s - these would only be re-evaluated if you have done some weird thing where a `MyIp` is re-evaluated each time it is accessed.  As in, when the function returns you'll have a fully evaluated list of `MyIp`s.

There is one slight issue, however, in that your function as implemented isn't particularly efficient.  Instead, I would recommend doing it in this slightly alternative way:

```
let rec GetIpRangeRec (startIp: MyIp) (endIp: MyIp) (ipList: MyIp list) = 
    if startIp <= endIp then
        GetIpRangeRec (startIp + 1) endIp (startIp :: ipList)
    else
        List.rev ipList
```

Basically, the issue is that every time you use the `@` operator to append to the end of a list, the runtime has to walk to the end of the list to do the append.  This means that you'll end up iterating over the list a whole bunch of times.  Instead, better simply to prepend (i.e. append, but to the front), and then reverse the list just before you return it.  This means that you only have to walk the list once, as prepending is always a constant-time operation (you just create a new list entry with a pointer to the previous front of the list).

Actually, since you probably don't want to use a pre-supplied list outside of your function, I would recommend doing it this way instead:

```
let GetIpRange startIp endIp = 
    let rec GetIpRangeRec (start: MyIp) (end: MyIp) (ipList: MyIp list) = 
        if start <= end then
            GetIpRangeRec (start + 1) end (start :: ipList)
        else
            List.rev ipList 

    GetIpRangeRec startIp endIp List.empty
```

(note that I haven't tested this, so it may not work totally perfectly).  If you do want to be able to pre-supply a starting list, then you can just stick with the first one.

Also, bear in mind that while lists are usually fine for sequential access, they're terrible for random accesses.  If you need to be doing random lookups into the list, then I would recommend using a call to `List.toArray` once you get the complete list back.  Probably no need to bother if you'll just be iterating over it sequentially though.

I'll make one more point though:  From a total functional programming 'purist's' perspective your first implementation may not be totally 'functional', but the only mutability involved is all hidden away inside the function.  That is, you're not mutating anything that is passed in to the function.  This is perfectly fine from a functional purity perspective and might be good for performance.  Remember that F# is functional-first, not zealously fuctional-only ;)

EDIT:  Just thought of one more thing I would like to add:  I don't know exactly how your `MyIp` types are constructed, but if you can build them out of numbers, it might be worth looking at using a sequence comprehension like `seq {1 .. 100}` and then piping that to a `map` to create the `MyIp`s, e.g. `seq {1 .. 100} |> Seq.map makeIp |> Seq.toList`.  This would be the easiest way, but would only work if you can simply specify a simple number range.

Comment: Thanks for the details here and the hints. That's what I was looking for. Internally the `MyIp` actually uses the number representation (at least in the overload for `+`). Maybe it's worth exploiting this.

Answer (score 2):

`Seq` is lazy in F#, ie there are benefits to caching the results occassionally. F# `List` is not lazy, it's an immutable single linked list that won't get any benefits from caching.